# How can I get the indices where array entries match a particular condition?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the indices where array entries match a particular condition?

Say, want to match device = '1'...

```
[
    { device: '1', type: 'a' },
    { device: '2', type: 'b' },
    { device: '3', type: 'c' },
    { device: '1', type: 'd' }
]
```

The returned result should be array [0,3].

Does JavaScript have a findIndexAll() or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried to loop over the array and checking the `device` property at each iteration to see if it matches `1`? What's the issue you're currently facing and have you made an attempt to solve this yourself (if so, please post what you've tried).

Comment: You can do `json.filter(d => d.device == '1').map(d => json.indexOf(d))`, it returns `[0, 3]`, but there might be better way to do that.

Comment: Please provide what you tried so we may help you fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce to push the indices of the matching entries into an accumulator array:

```js
const arr = [
    { device: '1', type: 'a' },
    { device: '2', type: 'b' },
    { device: '3', type: 'c' },
    { device: '1', type: 'd' }
]

const r = arr.reduce((a,c,i) => (c.device==='1' && a.push(i), a), [])

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to do this using a combination of "map" and "indexOf", like this:

```js
function findIndexesByProperty(array, property, value) {
  return array.map((item, index) => item[property] === value ? index : -1)
    .filter(index => index !== -1);
}

const data = [{
    device: '1',
    type: 'a'
  },
  {
    device: '2',
    type: 'b'
  },
  {
    device: '3',
    type: 'c'
  },
  {
    device: '1',
    type: 'd'
  },
];

const indexes = findIndexesByProperty(data, 'device', '1');
console.log(indexes); // Output: [0, 3]
```

Comment: There's no `indexOf` in your code? (Which is good, as it would be rather inefficient if it were)